# Replacing the default Windows XP screensaver image

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, screensaver

How can I replace the image which is shown when using the default "Windows XP" screensaver? What is the registry key of interest? I would like to replace the Windows XP logo with a custom logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look round the web seems to imply that the image is hard coded into the screensaver. There's a couple of things you could do though...

1) Use a commercial "make a bouncing screensaver with a logo of my choice" program. Caveat Emptor here though. Screensavers downloaded from the web seem to have a higher than normal incidence of malware.

2) If it is a registry hack, you can download a registry monitoring program (sysinternals has one), fire off the screen saver and see what sections of the registry are read.

3) Use a resource editor to change the image in the default screensaver.

All that's vague, and I apologise for that. Good luck with your search!